# Max length of Elasticsearch field names

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any restriction of the length of field names in JSON documents stored in Elasticsearch?

The maximum length of Elasticsearch indices is 255 characters. But I didn't find any restrictions of field names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for indices it's currently [set to 255](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/5.x/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/MetaDataCreateIndexService.java#L108).

I couldn't find a limit for field names in a quick search through the source code. Also tried more than 6,000 and that worked without problems. So I guess for regular use cases you should be ok ;-)